# Android: DetailActivity has leaked ServiceConnection

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-youtube-api

I have a `ViewPager` which is dynamically populated by a list of `Fragment`s. All these `Fragment`s have a `RecyclerView` consisting of multiple types of elements (each `ItemView` is different from the other and there is no way of knowing which type of view would be at which position). To populate this `RecyclerView`, we are using multiple corresponding types of `ViewHolders`. One of these is a `YoutubeHolder` and is supposed to open up a `YoutubeStandalonePlayer` instance. Here is my problem: Whenever the orientation changes or the back button is pressed on a `Fragment` containing a `YoutubeHolder`, I get an exception saying `DetailActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@1ece5fa2 that was originally bound here`. This also happens if I swipe between `Fragment`s. Now, it's not like I'm not releasing the `YoutubeThumbnailLoader` obtained in the `onInitializationSuccess` call. I have read a lot of questions on StackOverflow regarding this, but nothing seems to be helping me!

Here is the code for my `YoutubeHolder`:

```
public class ElementYoutubeHolder extends BaseElementHolder implements YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {

YouTubeThumbnailView thumbView;
YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbLoader;
String youTubeKey = null;
String videoId;

public ElementYoutubeHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
}

@Override
public void bind(final StoryElement element) {
    if (element.url() == null) {
        return;
    }
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(element.url());
    videoId = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
    thumbView.setTag(videoId);
    thumbView.initialize(youTubeKey, this);
    thumbView.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);

    itemView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {
            itemView.removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(this);
            if (thumbLoader != null) {
                try {
                    thumbLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(null);
                    thumbLoader.release();
                    Log.v(ElementYoutubeHolder.class.getSimpleName(), "thumbLoader released");
                } catch (IllegalStateException ile) {
                    //May be this youtube thumbnail loader already is released, so catch the exception here
                }
            }
        }
    });
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) view.getContext(), youTubeKey, videoId);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View getView() {
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public boolean recreate() {
    return true;
}

/**
 * Static method to get YoutubeHolder
 *
 * @param parent {@link ViewGroup}
 * @return {@link ElementYoutubeHolder}
 */
public static ElementYoutubeHolder create(ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.v(ElementYoutubeHolder.class.getSimpleName(), "created element youtube holder");
    View view = ViewUtils.inflate(R.layout.qs_story_layout_youtube, parent);
    ElementYoutubeHolder holder = new ElementYoutubeHolder(view);
    holder.thumbView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.qs_youtube_thumbnail);
    holder.youTubeKey = parent.getContext().getString(R.string.qs_youtube_key);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
    Log.v(ElementYoutubeHolder.class.getSimpleName(), "initialization success");
    String videoId = (String) youTubeThumbnailView.getTag();
    youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(videoId);
    thumbLoader = youTubeThumbnailLoader;
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    Log.v(ElementYoutubeHolder.class.getSimpleName(), "initialization failure: " + youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
    thumbLoader = null;
}

public void recycleYoutubeThumbnailLoader() {
    if (thumbLoader != null) {
        thumbLoader.release();
    }
}
}
```

I am also calling `recycleYoutubeThumbnailLoader()` from the adapter like this:

```
@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(BaseElementHolder holder) {
    if(holder instanceof ElementYoutubeHolder){
        ((ElementYoutubeHolder) holder).recycleYoutubeThumbnailLoader();
        Log.v(StoryAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "thumnailLoader recycled");
    }
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
}
```

One more thing: this error is not crashing my app. My app is running normally. Only this error shows up on the LogCat, and I would like to fix it because it might cause bigger problems later on.

And here is the stack trace:

```
06-14 19:44:49.345 4688-4688/com.example.sampleapp E/ActivityThread: Activity com.example.sampleapp.DetailActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@1ece5fa2 that was originally bound here
                                                                             android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.example.sampleapp.DetailActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@1ece5fa2 that was originally bound here
                                                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1083)
                                                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:977)
                                                                                 at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1794)
                                                                                 at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1777)
                                                                                 at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.example.sampleapp.viewholders.ElementYoutubeHolder.bind(ElementYoutubeHolder.java:42)
                                                                                 at com.quintype.coreui.story.StoryPresenter.bind(StoryPresenter.java:281)
                                                                                 at com.example.sampleapp.adapters.StoryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(StoryAdapter.java:77)
                                                                                 at com.example.sampleapp.adapters.StoryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(StoryAdapter.java:40)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1560)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(Fra
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some service and called somewhere `bindService`. So, you just need call [unbindService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unbindService(android.content.ServiceConnection))

This is one of `Context` methods. If you open connection, you need to close it, in `onDestroy` methods (or when it's not needed more).

Comment: I don't seem to have called `bindService` anywhere and my app doesn't feature any services. If it a service in the Youtube API, I can't tell how to unbind it. The first line in the stack trace that is one of my app's is this: `thumbView.setTag(videoId);`